# Camera preview on RPi3 running Android-Things

Tags: android, android-layout, android-things

I try to port Google Sample App: Camera2Video to RPI3 running Android-Thing.

Unfortunately, the callback function from AutoFitTextureView in Camera2VideoFragment (line 128): onSurfaceTextureAvailable will be not called in Android-Thing and camera2 can not be opened.
Are there some restrictions for using TextureView in A-Thing?
The same app is running perfectly on normal Android device.

The modification of Camera2Base is running perfect and I'm getting still pictures from camera2 in ImageView but without preview.

Are there any way to get camera2 preview in Android-Thing?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing a similar issue: it can't create a TextureView whichI also needed for camera2 preview, since it complains about hardware acceleration not being enabled.